# (How) can I select a Windows Store app with a file browser?

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm working on an introspection utility which eventually asks the user to specify the executable to use for launching the application. Now I'd like to add support for so-called "Windows Store apps" (formerly known as "Metro" apps, I believe). However, it's not clear to me how they are stored locally.

I read about how Windows Store apps are [packaged and deployed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and apparently it's common to distribute them as `.appx` files, generated by tools like [`makeappx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, I don't see if/where they are stored locally.

Does it make sense to address them like ordinary executables at all, i.e. via a file name? Or is there rather a more appropriate method? I noticed that in the registry, some (all?) of the Windows Store apps I have installed are listed beneath

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\ActivatableClasses\Package
```

Is there some API available for handling this registry tree, to do stuff like "Get me the user-visible name" or "Get me the AppUserModelId so that I can launch the app"?